# Scala: Sequential Futures

Tags: scala, nested, concurrent.futures

I want to process this nested futures sequentially for each element that I pass with an'iterator.

I chained the futures with flatMap and Map  ,is this the correct way?

What should I do to perform the process in the desired way (shown below) with and without the use of any blocking tool?

```
object Main{

Iterator.foreach{e=>
process(e)
 }
}


object A {

def doOne(e): Future[Any] = Future {
println("startFirst");      Thread.sleep(3000);     
 }

def doTwo(Any): Future[Any] = Future {
println("startSecond");      Thread.sleep(1000);      
}


 def doThree(Any): Future[Any] = Future {
println("do 3");     Thread.sleep(1000);     
}

  def doFour(e,Any): Future[Unit] = Future {
println(s"do 4&processComplete$e");     Thread.sleep(1000);     
  }

def process(e):Future[Unit]={

val a= doOne(e)
.flatMAp{a=> doTwo(a)}
.flatMap{b=>doThree(b)}
.map{c=> doFour(c)}

 }
```

If I pass 3 elemnt (e1,e2,e3) to def process I expect the program to print:

```
    startFirst (e1)
    startSecond(e1)
    startThree (e1)
    startFour&processComplete  (e1)
    startFirst (e2)
    startSecond(e2)
    startThree (e2)
    startFour&processComplete  (e2)
    startFirst (e3)
    startSecond(e3)
    startThree (e3)
    startFour&processComplete  (e3)
```

Intead of :

```
    startFirst (e1)
    startFirst (e2)
    startFirst (e3)
    startSecond(e1)
    startSecond(e2)
    startSecond(e3)
    startThree (e1)
    startThree (e2)
    startThree (e3)
    startFour&processComplete  (e1)
    startFour&processComplete  (e2)
    startFour&processComplete  (e3)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
def sequentialTraverse_[A](col: IterableOnce[A])(f: A => Future[Any])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
  col.iterator.foldLeft(Future.successful(())) {
    case (accF, a) =>
      accF.flatMap(_ => f(a)).map(_ => ())
  }
```

Which you may also convert into an **extension method** so you can do something like:

```
List("A", "B", "C").sequentialTraverse_(process)
```

You can see it working [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/UF8NUq6pT5q6Cya37cXbhg/12).

Comment: To add a detail for readers who may be wondering this: the underscore at the end of the method name is an established naming convention (familiar in particular to Haskell developers) which usually means "we are not interested in the return value here, this function is supposed to be interesting for its effects".